# Object B in object A and reference of object A in object B without pointers

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, initialization, initializer-list

So what I wanted to do is to store:

- object B in object A and
- reference of object A in object B

while not using pointers.

The only difference between using pointers and references I try to avoid is accessing syntax. I don't want to write '->' each time I access an object A in object B.

Code I thought could work but throws segmentation fault:

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class B;
class A{
    B b;
public:
    A();
};
#endif
```

B.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

class A;
class B{
    A& a;
public:
    B(A &_a);
};
#endif
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

A::A():b(B(*this)){}
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

B::B(B &_b):a(_b){}
```

First thing I thought was causing segmentation fault was using 'this' keyword (of uninititialized instance) in initializer-list, but I've read that as long as I don't access it everything should be OK. My constructors are empty so I don't what could be wrong.

Is it possible to do it similar to how I am doing it? And if no then why and is there something that could allow me to not write '->'?

**EDIT:**
Indeed there were some compilation errors because it was just written as pseudocode just to not paste unnecessary code here so nobody has to waste time. After writing the pseudocode of course it compiled. [image: But] goo.gl/DHlM6X

But now it runs without seg fault. I guess there is something that I do differently in my project. I will have to test for some time why it doesn't work in project and I will post what was the problem so the Question could have real answer.

Comment: If I spelled everything right then yes, in codeblocks c++11 under arch.

Comment: Interesting.  AFAIK A.h should not compile as you have a regular variable to an incomplete type.

Comment: B's constructor definition has a different signature than its declaration, or am I seeing things now?

Comment: @Antua you have a few bugs in your code that cause it not to compile. Firstly, `A` needs the full definition of `B` because it has one as a member. That's easy to fix by adding `#include "B.h"` at the top of `A.h`. Secondly, the declaration of `B`'s constructor does not match the declaration in the definition. Also, you never instantiate an instance of `A` in your example program, so you shouldn't have a segmentation fault in it's constructor. Are you quite sure that you're compiling and running *this* code?

Comment: *is there something that could allow me to not write '->'?* -- Yes -- write `(*object).` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first it might seem a good idea to use references here and not to mess with pointers, but you don't help yourself with this. Why? A reference is meant to link to an object where you can be sure the linked object lives longer than the reference.

So your code

```
class B{
  A& a;
};
```

basically states: "For every object of type `B` there is a known, not changeable object of type `A` that exists before the object of type `B` is created and will still live at the time the `B`-object is destructed".

At the same time your code

```
class A{
  B b;
};
```

states: "Every object of type `A` consists of an object of type `B`", which basically tells to compiler to allocate memory for an object of type `A` (including the space for `B b`), then construct an object of type `B` at the right position inside that memory and then construct an object of type `A`. But in this example A is constructed **after** B and destroyed **before** B.

Both statements exclude each other.

So either you switch to pointers (which state "The object knows about another object of type `X`" and can be the `nullptr`) or you might consider doing something like this:

```
class Combined{
  A a;
  B b;
}
```

and then add functions that need to know about both objects in the `Combined` class.

In the standard i found the following about your problem and why it shouldn't work at all:

> 9.3.2 **The this pointer [class.this]**
>   In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword this
>   is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called. The type of this in a member function of
>   a class X is X*. If the member function is declared const(...)

So from what i can say, `this` has only defined behaviour "inside the body of a non-static member function". Some compilers allow `this`, `typeid(this)` or `sizeof(this)` also in other parts of the class, but i couldn't find this in the standard.

Comment: I think that memory allocation happens right before constructor is fired, so A has its memory while B is created. And it just does not has reference to B till B ends its initialization, and then A can finish its initialization writing reference to right place. My program is guaranteed to have both objects from beginning to end, so there would not be need to change reference or store nullptr.

Combined class would just do a lot of mess because both classes just do different things, but has to relay on each other. I would rather use pointers :/ 

Still your answer is the best so far.

Comment: Yes, memory allocation happens before the constructor is fired. But its just empty (or uninitialized) memory until the construction is finished. So order should be this: -memory for A is allocated - A.b is constructed using a pointer to A -A is constructed using whatever is inside your contructors body. This means a pointer to A is used before A is constructed. This might work on some compilers, but i would not recommend it, since its not guaranteed to work on all compilers (at least from what i've read in the standard).